# Converting PHP strings to binary format and reconverting them when connecting to server

Tags: php

I'm looking to code a php script that would connect to a server using binary protocol, send queries and receive data from it. I wondered how I can implement this in php? So far I have:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("111.111.10.10", "2222", $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "You message");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

When I speak of binary, I don't mean the underlying of computer language, I mean that the specific string that is sent to the server should be converted in "0101001", since that is the way server reads and converts info. I need a way to convert php strings to this format and reconvert them back.

I will explain if you don't fully understand the question.

Comment: What comes to mind is a characterwise encoding to bits. Something like: 'Get first letter of string, convert it to it's integer value, convert that number to binary and send it.' Though...why would you want to go to this much trouble? Why not just send the string itself? Because it will BE ones and zeros along the way.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Doing a conversion like the one you're proposing in PHP would result in having a `string` which contains (ascii encoded) ones and zeroes because PHP has no underlying binary data type. Hence you'll be expanding the length of your data seven times (seven bits in an ascii character) and you'll also be making it unintelligible to the other end of the socket which expects (ascii encoded) bytes.

Comment: Yes, true Refugnic. Well, the server is already programmed to transfer data that way, that is why I have to use this in php to display data on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [pack](http://php.net/pack) and [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) to convert to/from binary

Comment: please see the comment I addressed to RefugnicEternium the results are the same - a string containing ascii ones and zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

To create a binary string from a string, you need a few steps. First change all charactors to numeric `ord()` and then convert the number to decimal `decbin`. I also used `str_pad` to make it have 8bits per charactor.

I added a spacer for readability

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello world';
$l = strlen($str);
$result = '';
while ($l--) {
    $result = str_pad(decbin(ord($str[$l])), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' - ' . $result;
}
print $result;

//01001000 - 01100101 - 01101100 - 01101100 - 01101111 - 00100000 - 01110111 - 01101111 - 01110010 - 01101100 - 01100100
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

They already are in a binary representation. Transmitting them to the server via `fwrite` should be enough.

The other end of the socket will receive the binary string and process it as is.